# Inner join "many-to-many" table rows as array

Tags: postgresql

I'm relatively new to PostgreSQL and trying to figure out how to solve the following scenario. Let's say I have three tables:

**stores**

```
| store_id |
|----------|
|    1     |
|    2     |
|    3     |
```

**products**

```
| product_id |
|------------|
|     1      |
|     2      |
|     3      |
```

**store_has_product**

```
| store_id | product_id |
|----------|------------|
|     1    |      3     |
|     1    |      2     |
|     2    |      1     |
|     3    |      3     |
|     1    |      1     |
|     3    |      1     |
|     3    |      2     |
```

And now I'm trying to build a query to join all products to the stores table and group them in an array, so that I have an output like this:

```
| store_id | products  |
|----------|-----------|
|    1     | {3, 2, 1} |
|    2     | {2}       |
|    3     | {3, 1, 2} |
```

I know that Arrays are possible with PostgreSQL, but I don't get how to write such a query and probably already spent too much time thinking about a solution.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you provide us the query you have built so far?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using version `8.4` or later you can use `array_agg`:

```
SELECT store_id, array_agg(product_id::text) as products
FROM store_has_product
GROUP BY store_id
```